# Resque + Sinatra + Heroku how to run the jobs continuously

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, rack, resque

I have already setup Redis + Resque and deploy on heroku already. Everything works fine, and the jobs are added to the queue correctly. But it won't be run until I run command

`heroku run rake jobs:work`

How do I tell heroku to run the jobs in the queue automatically in background?

I'm using Sinatra and not Rails.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm using heroku bamboo though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a worker process to your application that will automatically run the `rake jobs:work` process for you continuously.

You can do this via the UI on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better (IMHO) way to do this using IronWorker. Iron.io will basically always be cheaper, and I find the approach easier to set up and use. http://www.iron.io/